# iOS rename/delete albums of photos

Tags: ios, alassetslibrary, alasset, ios-camera, camera-roll

I am able to add photos and create albums from my app but I also want to be able to rename/delete albums and pictures in these albums. I know Apple have restrictions but is it possible at least to manage the albums and photos created by my application? (ALAsset and ALAssetLibrary) 
I understand I can't do anything to the already existing albums and photos in the Camera row and I am ok with this.

Answer (score 0):

If you created an album, so that the album is `editable`, then the presence or absence of an asset in that album is up to you. But the name of the asset is not up to you, and basically you don't have the kind of access to the user's photo library that would permit fine-grained management of albums and their content. Only the user can do that (using the Photos app) - to the extent that even the Photos app permits it. That is why apps that do this sort of thing use *internal* "albums" to present the images. You can clump any images you like into your interface and *show* them to the user as an "album" of your own.